# Using dplyr pivot functions in Spark using sparklyr

Tags: dplyr, sparklyr

I'm working with a large dataset from CMS and it's currently stored in a Hive table connected to my Spark cluster.

To date I haven't been able to get dplyr pivot functions to work so I've been collecting the data and then running a whole bunch of dplyr verbs on the data in R.

I've recently run out of memory with some of my latest processing steps and I'm wondering if my manipulations can be done in Spark rather than locally.

TL;DR

Does dplyr pivot_longer run on Spark?

Comment: technically pivot_longer is from tidyr, but yes, you can now use pivot_longer and pivot_wider in sparklyr (with some limitations).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can run dplyr verbs on spark dataframes, back to the drawing board on my yarn cluster

```
library(sparklyr)
library(tidyverse)

spark_install(version = "3.0.3", hadoop_version = "3.2")

spark_home_set('C:/Users/Me/AppData/Local/spark/spark-3.0.3-bin-hadoop3.2')

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

tbl_mtcars <- copy_to(sc, mtcars, "spark_mtcars")

x <- tbl_mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  pivot_longer(!cyl,names_to = "variable",values_to = "values") %>% 
  collect()
```